# Multiple {n} quantifiers regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to have multiple quantifiers in a regex?
Say I have the following regex:

`[A-Z0-9]{44}|[A-Z0-9]{36}|[A-Z0-9]{30}`

I want to match any string which is either 30, 36 or 44 chars long. Is it possible to write this shorter in any way? Something like the following:

`[A-Z0-9<]{30|36|44}`?

**Edit:** Seeing the answers I assume there is not really a way in which you can write the above shorter. The best solution would be to solve it programmatically I guess. Thanks for the input.

Comment: What regex flavor it is?

Comment: pcre I guess. I changed the question to _multiple_ instead of _variable_ btw.

Comment: But it has to be _exactly_ those numbers?  Not any number between 30 & 44?

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of `{n,m}` and `{n,}` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief

Note that your regex performs much better than any other answers you'll get on your question, but since your question is actually about *simplifying/shortening* your regex, you can use this.

Your original regex (38 characters):

```
[A-Z0-9]{44}|[A-Z0-9]{36}|[A-Z0-9]{30}
```

Your original regex with modifications so that we can use it to test against multiline input (44 characters):

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]{44}|[A-Z0-9]{36}|[A-Z0-9]{30})$
```

---

### Code

My original regex (32 characters):

```
([A-Z0-9]){44}|(?1){36}|(?1){30}
```

My original regex with modifications so that we can use it to test against multiline input (38 characters):

```
^(?:([A-Z0-9]){44}|(?1){36}|(?1){30})$
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YNsR2N/1)

---

### Explanation

- `([A-Z0-9]){44}|(?1){36}|(?1){30}` Match either of the following

  - `([A-Z0-9]){44}` Match any character in the set (`A-Z` or `0-9`) exactly 44 times. This also captures a single character in the set into capture group 1. We will later use this capture group through recursion.
  - `(?1){36}` Recurse the first subpattern exactly 36 times
  - `(?1){30}` Recurse the first subpattern exactly 30 times

Comment: Nice, thank you for your thorough answer. TIL Recursing subpatterns.

Comment: Good answer. A JavaScript/TypeScript flavor of this regex would be `/([A-Z0-9]){44}|(\1){36}|(\1){30}/`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check your input contains only uppercase letters `[A-Z]` and digits `[0-9]` to test whether it is a string. Eliminate `[A-Z0-9]` part for this reason. Now, you can specify multiple quantifiers as follows:

```
^(?:.{30}|.{36}|.{44})$
```

If you need to do that check strictly. You can use this regex without typing `[A-Z0-9]` three times:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]*$)(?:.{30}|.{36}|.{44})$
```

You have the `[A-Z0-9]` part only once and a generic `.` to check the length of string.

Comment: Actually it's shorter and doesn't perform unnecessary check (?=[A-Z0-9]*?). Isn't it? I'll edit it for you in a minute.

Comment: You are assuming that the regex is being applied to an expression which is alone on a line, but there is nothing in the question to suggest that this assumption is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want

```
[A-Z0-9]{30}([A-Z0-9]{6}([A-Z0-9]{8})?)?
```

This isn't actually simpler, mind you.

Comment: If you are using a regex dialect which supports this, that's obviously an attractive simplification; but the question is simply tagged [tag:regex] (in violation of the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info guidelines,](/tags/regex/info) we might note).

Comment: Isn't it a match for all strings with length greater than or equal to 30?

Comment: Huh? No, it accepts 30, with an optional additional 6, with an optional additional 8. Out of context, this will match a substring which matches these criterial in a line containing, say, arbitrary runs of whitespace around the match, or a longer string a substring of which matches these criteria (longest leftmost substring).

Comment: It's obvious. I mean this will return a match for range [0-29] due to the first part of the regex even for a string with length 34 for instance. But it should return a match only for the ones with length 30, 36, or 44. For this reason, I used the match-zero-or-one operator '?' in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you produce a test case e.g. on regex101.com where this doesn't do what is expected? Here's one which doesn't do what you seem to be claiming: https://regex101.com/r/zhBiO9/2

Comment: I read your comment about my assumption just now. You're already aware of the point that I try to explain. For your regex, if the input text is "TEST0STRING0LONGER0THAN0THIRTY1234", there's 1 match (corresponds to "TEST0STRING0LONGER0THAN0THIRTY"). To me, the result should no return match for this text, and the regex should only match a string that is either 30, 36, or 44 characters long. But I see your point as well. :) We're okay.